# How does Youtube implement live streaming

Tags: http, youtube, live-streaming, wowza

Monitoring your network while watching a Youtube live streaming (http://youtube.com/live/), you can see that they are downloading a file to your cache, and this file is actually the live stream.

Bitgravity use the same way to deliver their live stream since years (Check Twit.tv for example).

Does anyone know what is the server side used for this ? and how can someone achieve this instead of using Adobe FMS, Wowza or Red5 ?

Answer (score 9):

These guys have put together an [open source video streaming server](http://code.google.com/p/stream-m/), so you can look at the source code and see how they did it.

They wrote it in Java.

The current version is a **working prototype**, which showcases the main ideas. The main design goal is low resource usage.

Answer (score 2):

there can be many ways to implement streaming, i dont think google will let you know how they do that, but it can be done even by simple http, just a simple stream that sends the video data without the "range" header so its just go on and on